# Moved WordPress to host server and images have old url and won't display

Tags: wordpress

I moved my WordPress from my local PC to the host server using the export feature (ver 4.9.1) on Xampp Windows 10 . My issue is that after importing the WordPress site to my host (venuraIP) my images have the old urls still with prefix 127.0.0.1/ and don't load.

I have had to manually reload images to make them appear which is time consuming.

I also used a search replace plugin and this didn't work. My site settings are correct, permalinks are correct, I used more search and replace plugins but NOTHING.

> For example here is an image from a link which is incorrect.

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpresscrm/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/pexels-photo-45111.png" title="" alt="" />
```

> it should be /wp1/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/pexels-photo-45111.png" title="" alt="" />

```
www.andrewt.com.au/wp1/landpro2/
```

I checked many posts here which talk about search/replace plugins and permalinks settings but they haven't worked.

Comment: Give [Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) a crack. It works a treat when going from any environment to another, replaces all instances of URLs specified.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs in the database are fully qualified (eg: http://example.com/wp-content), so if you change the URL of the site, all database references need to be changed as well. There are a number of ways this can be done, for example exporting the database to text and using find/replace. Alternatively all media needs to be uploaded again (as you have found).

Comment: I have  a wordpress instance on my host server. So I need to delete my db and files , and use migrate db? I am a bit confused in what I need to do. The media files all had to be uploaded which took a while

Comment: The problem is that your database was setup on your local machine as 127.0.0.1, which is what is saved in your database. On the production host the URL is example.com (not 127.0.0.1), so all references in your database need to be changed. Either do this manually or use a utility/plugin like Migrate DB to do this for you. Once the database is updated to the correct location, wp should find your media on the host.

Comment: on the host server before i use mitigate db do I need to set up a default wordpress instance?

Comment: No, assuming you have already have wp and media copied from your local machine, just get the database from your local machine, either dump it with phpMyAdmin and find/replace URL or use Migrate DB, then import updated database into the wp on your host.

Comment: just having a look at migrate db, does duplicator  also do the same thing because most websites are advocating this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cpanel, you can search in phpmyadmin with old url and replace to new url.

Or

Before upload database, open sql database with nodepad or text editor like sublime. End replace the old url to new url.